# CSV export task

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need a task that outputs a CSV text file of a couple of tables about every 5 minutes.
Server is MSSQL 2008.
It is a production server.

requirements are:
* utf8 output
* '\t' or ';' cell separator
* '\n' row terminator
* file should be overwritten
* the output is a join of two tables (dbo.article and dbo.stock key being 'c_art')

Answer (score 1):

There's so little information in the question that I'm not entirely sure of your requirements, but you can use BCP in a scheduled task or as a stored procedure to accomplish this.

Command format:

```
BCP <table> out <filename> <switches>

The switches used here are:

    * -c Output in ASCII with the default field terminator (tab) and row terminator (crlf)
    * -t override the field terminator with ","
    * -T use a trusted connection. Note that U –P may be used for username/password
    * -S connect to this server to execute the command
```